# Setting up Bower with Gulp (and Web Starter Kit)

Tags: gulp, bower

With being able to have the bower_component folder outside of the `app` folder, how would it be possible to load the bower packages to work with gulp? The plan is to use Web Starter Kit that has gulp, browser sync already set up.

I think the set up will be to move the bower modules, with `gulp` - that has the task to copy the specified modules over to `app/scripts/vendors` or `app/styles/vendors`. So it will run two tasks (one for scripts and one for styles).

It will copy it over, and if newer updates were downloaded - replace the existing files. Concat and Minify no matter if serving or building.

Since WSK already builds a `main.js`, the bower packages will be built into a `library.js` file. Can someone guide me in the right direction to build this setup?

I've attached a few things I think the setup will need.

`app/index.html`

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Build into `/dist/scripts/venfors.js`

`gulpfile.js`

```
// Bower - bower_components directory - located to root folder
var directory = {
  bower = './bower_components/'
};

// Bower - Scripts
gulp.task('bower-scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    // AngularJS
    directory.bower+'bower_components/angular/angular.js'
  ])
    .pipe( --- Copy src to /app/scripts/vendor --- )
});
```

Not sure if there is there is anything more I need to do? Or if my setup is incorrect?

Reason why I want to keep the bower_components folder in the root folder NOT the app folder is to keep everything cleaner.

Brief: Gulp and WSK setup using bower, with bower_components folder outside of "App" folder.

Answer (score 2):

So, I believe this should help others:

What we are doing is copying over the packages over from `bower_components` folder in the `root` folder to our app scripts folder.

```
// Bower - Scripts
gulp.task('bower-scripts', function() {
  var directory = { bower : './bower_components/' };

  return gulp.src([
    directory.bower+'**/*.min.js'
  ])
    // Output Files
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/scripts/vendor'))
});
```

When we rung `gulp serve`, we need to add the `bower-scripts` task as a dependency to our `serve` task

In `index.html`, specify the bower package you want to use like so:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/library.min.js -->
    <script src="scripts/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Than when you run `gulp` (to build) or `gulp serve` (to test) - everything should fall into place.

If you can streamline this - or make it more efficient, than drop a line!

Comment: you can use a `.bowerrc` to define where you want your `bower_components` to be installed. It might be cleaner and easier to maintain than defining the directory.